# How to retrieve the label text and pass to a string in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am using a label with the text as numbers. The label text is populated from javascript as below:

```
document.getElementById("label").innerText = arrList[2];
```

I want to use this label text to pass to a string.

```
 string a = label.Text.
```

It is not working. The label text is empty even it has the value.
Help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

I am assuming You are using Server side ASP control as `Label`

something like this:

`<asp:Label runat="server" ID="label" />`

then it should be

```
document.getElementById('<%=label.ClientID%>').innerHTML = arrList[2];
```

Description:
While Rendering page inside browser ASP.Net run-time will change ID of Server Side Controls So You need to Specify those controls using `label.ClientID` their client id

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that, the id of the label is not just `label`. Right click on the label in browser, choose inspect element and you will find the id of the label.

It will be like `ContentPlaceHolder1_label` or `ct100_label` or something.

To avoid confusion like this, you should use `ClientID`:

```
document.getElementById('<%=label.ClientID %>').innerHTML = arrList[2];
```